# How do I make an ISO copy of a DVD movie?

Tags: debian, iso

I want to make backups of data and video DVDs, without recompressing or altering them. I just want an ISO that I can mount to act as if I inserted the DVD (this includes video DVDs).

I had previously used K9copy 2.3.6, which seemed to work fine except that every other DVD would have no sound when mounted and played like a DVD. I've now installed `dvdrip` but it seems more aimed at producing compressed video files with an interface that's somewhat more complicated than necessary for what I'm trying to do.

I tried using `dd` but it just comes up with a `disc not readable` result or something similar, even thought the disc is fine.

Comment: K9Copy requires you to select the audio tracks you want to copy (everytime before the copy job is started). If you forget to do that, you'll end up with a file without sound. Maybe that's what happened.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Method #1

I generally just do this via the command line if I want to copy a DVD to a directory and then make it into an ISO:

```
$ cd /dir/where/you/save/the/dvd
```

Now insert DVD to be copied:

```
$ dvdbackup -M
$ genisoimage -dvd-video -udf -o movie.iso /dir/where/you/save/the/dvd
$ eject /dev/dvd
```

#### Method #2

If on the other hand if I just want to make an ISO directly from a DVD:

```
$ genisoimage -dvd-video -udf -o movie.iso /dvd/mounted/to
```

#### Method #3

If you want to RIP or burn using a GUI then I'd suggest using K3b.

#### References

- [[one-liner]: How to Backup a Movie DVD via the Command Line on Fedora 14 & CentOS 5](http://www.lamolabs.org/blog/7325/one-liner-how-to-backup-a-movie-dvd-via-the-command-line-on-fedora-14-centos-5/)

Comment: I've noticed that Method 1 works really well, but Method #2 seems to produce an ISO which, when mounted, shows up as a DVD with the name "cdrom" or something similar (my DVD is mounted in `mnt/cdrom0`, maybe that's related). When I try to play it as a DVD it doesn't show video in VLC (on windows). I'm guessing it thinks it's a CD? Do you know why this might be happening?

Comment: @ArmanSchwarz I'm not sure why this would not be working but you may have better luck with this command which just omits the `-udf`. `genisoimage -dvd-video -o movie.iso /dvd/mounted/to`

Comment: Does method 1 work even with DVD encryption?

Comment: @FaheemMitha - yes. I've used this for any type of DVD.

Comment: genisoimage creates a new image and is not a faithful copy "without recompressing or altering". For a start, the volume name is lost; your Method #1 also only copies the DVD-Video content and not any other data on the disc.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a graphical tool I would suggest [K3b](http://www.k3b.org/).

If you want a command line utility that is not `dd`, you can have a look at `mkisofs` instead.